# Ruby koans: Stuck on koan 267

Tags: ruby, proxy

I've been looking online, but I can't seem to crack this poxy Proxy koan!
Here's what I have as my Proxy class:

```
class Proxy
  def initialize(target_object)
    @object = target_object
    # ADD MORE CODE HERE
    @messages = []
  end

  # WRITE CODE HERE
  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    if @object.respond_to?(method_name)
      @messages << method_name
      @object.__send__(method_name, *args)          
    end
  end


end
```

Further down the code a Proxy Television gets instantiated and has its .channel set to 10, thus:

```
tv = Proxy.new(Television.new)
tv.channel = 10
```

I'm NOW getting the following error:

```
expected 10 to equal [:channel=, :power, :channel]
```

I have so many questions, I'm not sure where to start:
WHY does the method_missing method return an Array?
WHY does the first element in the Array end with a '='?
WHY, when I add...

```
def channel
    @object.channel
end
```

...to the proxy, does the koans command line throw one of those elaborately drawn 'mountains are again merely mountains' errors?
And finally, can I quit now?

Any advice on these questions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't quit! :)

I guess the main thing that you have to understand is the method_missing method. Within the if statement, the last line takes the method that the target object (in this case an instance of Television) is calling and saves it in an array called @messages. When you do `tv.channel = 10`, your target object is calling the `channel=` method.

Since that's the last thing in the method, method_missing returns that array.

The first item in the array is simply the "channel=" method, which is a method naming convention in ruby.

As for the last question, it'll throw an error because you're calling the method from within itself, which in theory will go on forever.

I hope that makes some sense.

Comment: OK, so I've switched the order of the lines (see above): I forgot Ruby returns the last expression in a method. That'll teach me for cut and pasting someone else's code. Ruby just seems to have so many unspoken quirks. I wish it seemed more consistent. It seems like a language that's designed both to 'look like' English and then I wonder if seasoned coders like it because they want something a bit more playful and esoteric. I'm yet to become a fan.

Comment: I think ruby being highly readable is coupled with the quirks of the language, and you're right, they are mostly difficult to discover and when you do its a wtf moment. I think a lot of it does also come down to the fact that ruby allows you to do pretty much anything with it which makes it easy to mess something up but also gives you a lot of creative freedom with your code.